# Why is this giving me an unexpected T_STRING error?

Tags: php, upload

The line that has the error is this one:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

There is nothing physically wrong with it as far as I can see, yet I get this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /directory/listing/upload.php on line 12`

Sorry, let me clarify, I'm not trying to echo it or print it out, I'm trying to set the XML version.

There is no need for the upload.php code as it all works fine, it's just this one line.

Also, (yes I know, w3schools which I'm only using as an EXAMPLE) w3chools has it set out like this to set it?

[Pastebin code here](http://pastebin.com/jTfp7frV)

[and I guess if it helps, I'm following these tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImIIHXRlL4k)

[XML example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/)

Comment: Paste the upload.php script here

Comment: Please write your question in details.

Comment: Updated now @Prasannjit

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. You're setting a XML header on HMTL output? The code you've posted is not the code that is giving you the error message either.

Comment: I think I have got confused along the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or do it with echo:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
```

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>
```